# cakephp3 not working after uploading to production server

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I developed my cakephp3 website in windows environment using xampp, mysql and apache, after development, I uploaded the whole website into my Linux hosting, and my chrome browser keeps giving the below error message when I access the website, is there any reason that causes the error?

This page isn’t working

website is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Infact I decided to freshly install a cakephp 3.5.2 version on my windows environment, make sure it works, upload to my linux production server, same error happens, so I know it is not my code that causes the problem.

Comment: Can you check with the error log?

Comment: could be a problem with permissions, could be the php version... as suggested check the error log in your server to see what is the error

Comment: the error log file is empty, I verified the PHP version is the same as what I have in development. it is like nothing execute at all, just shows http error 500, even a new cakephp once upload to server shows 500 error

Comment: thanks, i understand now, you need to check apache error log, it shows "You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP"